# How to apply filter on get_the_post_thumbnail()

Tags: filters, post-thumbnails

my client want me to add a custom fields for thumbail, so the logic will be

if custom_thumnail is empty, render the origina.
But i don't like idea of writing if statments everywhere + am using SEO plugins for open graph and images, so now i have to use filters to implement the custom thumbail.

i was thinking of wp filters but i didn't find one for get_the_post_thumbnail.

```
apply_filter('get_the_post_thumbnail',function(){
//my if statments
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`post_thumbnail_html`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/) filter.
This filter is applied in the return of the [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) function.

```
apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_html', $html, $post->ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr );
```